# Нужен скрипт который оприделяет номер слайда owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Доброго времени суток, нужен скрипт который будет оприделять номер слайда в owl carousel, и прятать нектороые блоки в соответствии от номера слайда. Зачем нужен? Есть owl carousel, у которой есть кнопки ( мои кастомные ( простые блоки )) loop я отключил ( тоесть моя карусель не прокручивается ), есть 3 слайда, вот то мне нужно - чтобы на первом слайде пряталась одна кнопка, на втором не прятались вообще, на на третьем пряталась последняя кнопка ( фактически мне нужно чтобы кнопки прятались на первом и последнем слайде)

Answer (score 3):

Я буду говорить про Owl Carousel 2. У Owl есть [события](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html), к которым можно подписаться и в [объекте](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#data) события будет номер активного слайда.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();
// Случаешь события карусели:
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var item = event.item.index;     // Позиция текущего слайда
  if (item === 1) {
    // Первый слайд активен
  }
})
```